# How to get SQL Join Output in the binary form

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, pivot

I have 2 tables:

Patient Visit Table

```
Visit ID    Patient ID  Date    Disease ID
   101         1       22-Feb       11
   102         5       5-Apr        22
   103         3       2-Jul        77
   104         2       4-Feb        55
   105         6       5-Jan        99
   106         2       6-Jan        66
   107         2       8-Jan        77
   108         7       9-Jan        44
   109         5       22-Jan       88
   110         1       23-Jan       33
```

and 2nd table is,

Disease Table

```
 Disease ID Disease Name

      11    Asthama
      22    TB
      33    Flu
      44    AIDS
      55    Cancer
      66    Heart Disease
      77    ABC
      88    XYZ
      99    MNO
```

I want the output as follows:
The table with Patient ID as Row and Disease as columns, The binary values indicating which patient has which disease.

What query should i use?

[The table with Patient ID as Row and Disease as columns, The binary values indicating which patient has which disease](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gK0i6.png)

Comment: Is this for SQL Server or MySQL? You have both tags on this question.

Comment: Search PIVOT. There have been a lot of answers for that.

Comment: This is called pivot table and you can find answers to both mysql and sql server here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you are using SQL Server, hope this could help. Using `Case Expression`

```
select t1.patient_id,
    case when t2.disease_name='Asthma' then 1 else 0 end as Asthma,
    case when t2.disease_name='TB' then 1 else 0 end as TB,
    case when t2.disease_name='Flu' then 1 else 0 end as Flu,
    case when t2.disease_name='AIDS' then 1 else 0 end as AIDS,
    case when t2.disease_name='Cancer' then 1 else 0 end as Cancer,
    case when t2.disease_name='Heart Disease' then 1 else 0 end as 'Heart Disease',
    case when t2.disease_name='ABC' then 1 else 0 end as ABC,
    case when t2.disease_name='XYZ' then 1 else 0 end as XYZ,
    case when t2.disease_name='MNO' then 1 else 0 end as MNO
from #table1 t1
left join #table2 t2
on t1.Disease_id=t2.Disease_id
order by t1.patient_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT PatientID, [Asthama],[TB],[Flu],[AIDS],[Cancer],[Heart Disease], [ABC],[XYZ],[MNO]
FROM
(SELECT P.PatientID,D.Disease from Patient P inner join Disease D on     P.DiseaseID=D.DiseaseID) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
count(Disease)
FOR Disease IN ([Asthama],[TB],[Flu],[AIDS],[Cancer],[Heart Disease],[ABC],[XYZ],[MNO])
) AS PivotTable;
```